# How do I add Dynamic Variables in Apptimize with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, variables, dynamic, addition

The Apptimize has a well is illustrated document for Objective C, but not much for Swift. I was successfully able to add **dynamic variables** to my **Apptimize** project with **ObjC** code, but i did **not** find any property with which i can do the same with **Swift**.

For Objective C - ApptimizeString(searchServerURL, @"http://byname.yourapp.com");

Here **searchServerURL** can be changed dynamically using the Apptimize portal for Dynamic Variables.

Can someone find me a way to **add Dynamic Variable to with Swift**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

source: http://apptimize.com/docs/faq/sdk/#dynamicvariable-swift

Apptimize works well with apps written in swift. Follow the integration instructions (they are the same as for an obj C app). To use dynamic variables do this also:

1. Create a bridging header if needed
2. Import Apptimize in bridging header:

   ```
   #import "Apptimize/Apptimize.h"
   ```
3. Import a dynamic variables support file that wraps your dynamic variables (call it whatever you want):

   ```
   #import "ApptimizeSwiftDynVars.h"
   ```
4. In header ApptimizeSwiftDynVars.h:

   ```
   #import 
   @interface ApptimizeSwiftDynVars : NSObject
       + (NSString*)yourDynVarString;
       // Or additional and other types of Apptimize dynamic variables
   @end
   ```
5. In implementation ApptimizeSwiftDynVars.m:

   ```
   #import "ApptimizeSwiftDynVars.h"

   ApptimizeString(yourDynVarString, @"default string for the variable");
   @implementation ApptimizeSwiftDynVars : NSObject
   + (NSString*)yourDynVarString {
      return [yourDynVarString stringValue];
   }
   @end
   ```
6. From your Swift code use the variable:

   ```
   self.dynamicLabel.text = ApptimizeSwiftDynVars.yourDynVarString()
   ```

Comment: Thanks Ben. They just updated their doc a few weeks ago.

Comment: looking at your answer I would suggest not to use **self** (point 6) in swift code unless you are using user property in closure or block.